Struggling with using the LDR instruction in ARM assembly
I use an M1 MacBook Pro.
I am trying the load a value I put in the .data segment in my assembly code, but when I look at the value of the register using LLDB, it shows me 0x0.
Here's the code:
.global _main
.extern print
.extern printInt
.extern exit
.align 4
    
.text
_main:
    ldr x0, =num
    b exit
   
.data
num: .word 5


Don't worry about the exit label I branch to, I have seperately defined that in another
assembly file.
And here's the register read just before executing the LDR instruction:
General Purpose Registers:
        x0 = 0x0000000000000001
        x1 = 0x000000016fdff2d0

And here's the register read just after executing the LDR instruction:
General Purpose Registers:
        x0 = 0x0000000000000000
        x1 = 0x000000016fdff2d0

I am also really struggling with learning Assembly on this machine, so if you have any helpful tools I can learn using, it would be really helpful if you share them.
I have tried searching up what the LDR instruction does, but the ARM's website is really obscure and difficult to process and other tools aren't helpful. I have no idea what's going on half the time.

ldr x0, =num should load the address of num which is most definitely not 0x0000000000000001. As such, you likely made some mistake during debugging. Anyway, you should then do a ldr x0, [x0] to load the value. Also .word is 32 bit so you either want to use a 32 bit register or .long

@Jester Changing from .word to .long had practically no effect on the code, and adding the ldc x0, [x0] gave me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) or in non-debugger terms, a segmentation fault, because I tried to access 0x0.

Did you remember to link yoour object file into a binary?  If yes, what command did you type to do so?

@Jester: According to Siguza (How to load data by label on Apple Silicon (ARM64)?), ldr x0, =num doesn't work on Darwin (because it would expand to something that involves a text relocation, but __TEXT is read-only and the dynamic linker isn't willing to work around that).  And the OP doesn't mention running Linux on their MacBook.  IDK, maybe something's changed, since the OP claims they were able to single-step past that ldr.

@PeterCordes For some weird reason lldb doesn't show me the expansion of any instruction, I am getting exactly the code I wrote. (Must be some dubugging thing)

@PeterCordes Also I do use MacOS

You might be doing source-level debugging.  To see the actual machine instructions, tell LLDB to work in disassembly mode.

I'll be sure to try that!

This is the fault of Apple's new linker.
For a long time, Apple had been using their ld64 linker for all of their platforms. And in this answer, I explain why using ldr xN, =... is broken on macOS, and what to use instead.
Now, I do think that some choices made about the internal workings of the Mach-O LLVM pipeline (specifically about segment relocations) make it really hard to properly support this "emit-a-pointer-and-load-it-by-pc-relative-label" for Darwin targets. But the specific way in which this failure manifests depends on choices made by the linker. Ideally the linker would identify that this was gonna be a problem and error out at link-time. But ld64 seems to be blissfully unaware of runtime restrictions and simply emits a pointer in a segment where trying to rebase it will crash the process.
But that was last year.
In Xcode 15, Apple has deprecated ld64 and replaced it with a new default that I've been calling dyld-ld for lack of a better name.
Running what on this new ld or invoking it with -v used to identify it as part of the dyld source tree back in Xcode 15.0:
PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:dyld-1015.7

Though it seems to have since been broken out into its own project:
PROGRAM:ld PROJECT:ld-1115.7.2

Unfortunately it's closed source, so we can't just go and examine it. But from the behaviour it exhibits, I'm pretty sure it's not a fork of ld64, but a rewrite from scratch.
Now, ld64 is still shipped as ld-classic and can be selected on the clang command line with -ld_classic. If you compile your code with that and then run dyld_info -fixups on your binary, you will see the rebase that is supposed to get applied (which will make the binary crash on launch).
If you link with dyld-ld (which can be explicitly selected with -ld_new, though that is the default anyway), then dyld_info -fixups will just not show a rebase for that pointer at all. And if you examine it in a disassembler, you will find that it simply has the value 0. This means that such binaries will now launch... but then very likely just crash on some NULL pointers. And that's what you're seeing in lldb.
So yeah, different symptom, same broken feature. You should still use adrp+add as I explain in my other answer.

I am sick of this documentation-less void in MacOS assembly programming. How the hell do you know all this stuff?? Do you have any resources you could share?

How do I know all this? Well, I've been doing security research on Apple platforms since late 2016, and that just requires deep dives into things. And I'm the de-facto maintainer of the checkra1n jailbreak, which, for complex reasons, uses a fake dyld during boot, and the first time I ran into dyld-ld was because our fake dyld stopped building with Xcode 15, and I had to spend a day working around that. But resources on this topic... that's a hard ask, because most of this knowledge is cobbled together from tiny pieces over the years.

About codesigning I know because I've been doing kernel hacking for many years, so for that: XNU source. The part about dyld-ld: if you have an hour to spare at some point, browse through /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ and try to figure out what every binary there does. You don't need to dig into each one, just get a broad understanding of what the toolchain even includes. For asm quirks: a combination of clang -S, LLVM source, various open source code bases, and not least just compiling things and then looking at them in radare2.

Also: the part about dyld-ld emitting NULL instead of a rebase-able pointer I learned today, because Peter Cordes commented on your post and wondered whether something had changed, so I wrote a small assembly snippet, compiled it, and saw that it no longer crashed on launch, and then I went to examine why. So it's less "knowing stuff" and more "knowing how to figure stuff out on the fly", which... is just a skill you acquire with time, as you gain a more comprehensive understanding of all the different parts of a system you're working with.

Cool! I will try your advice and try to follow onto the updates for the linker and pray to god they fix it. Part of me want to just get a job there and fix all this myself.
